# When should my indexes have the active column?

Tags: mysql, performance, indexing

I have several tables and I'm wondering if my composite index is helpful or not.  I am using `MySQL 5+` but I guess this would apply to any database (or not?).

Anyway, say I the following table:

```
username           active
-----------------------------------
Moe.Howard              1
Larry.Fine              0
Shemp.Howard            1
```

So I normally select like:

```
select * from users where username = 'shemp.howard' and active = 1;
```

The `active=1` is used in many of our tables.  Normally, my index would be on the `username` column but I'm thinking of added the active flag as well (to the same index).

My logic is that as the query engine is scanning through the index, it would be scanning against an index like:

```
moe.howard,1
shemp.howard,1
larry.fine,0
```

and find `Shemp` before it hits the inactive users (Larry).

Now, our `active` columns are usually `TINYINTS` and `Unsigned`.  But I'm concerned the index might be backward!

```
larry.fine,0
moe.howard,1
shemp.howard,1
```

How should I best handle this and make sure my indexes are correct?  Should I not add the active column to the same index as username?  Or should I create a separate index for the active and make it descending?

Thanks.

Comment: And here comes the golden rule for finding the appropriate index: Try it out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you combine those two fields in a composite index with the `active` flag as the second part of the key, then the index order will only depend on that value when (iff) the name field for two or more rows is identical (which seems unlikely in this situation based on the assumption that one would want user names in a system to be unique).  The first key in the composite index will define the order of the keys whenever they are different. In other words, if the user name is unique, then adding the active flag as the second segment of a composite index will not change the order of the index.

Also, note that for the example query, the database won't "scan" the index to find the value. Rather it will seek to the first matching entry, which in the example given consists of a single match.  The "scan" would happen if multiple entries pass the WHERE clause.

Having said that, unless there are lots of cases where you have duplicate names, my initial reaction would be to not create the composite key.  If the names are "generally" unique, then you would not be buying a lot of savings with the composite key.  On the other hand, if there are generally quite a few duplicate names with differing `active` flag values, it could help.  At that point, you may need to just test.

Comment: This makes sense.  Because my where clause is limiting my results to one record, because usernames are unique, the active flag really won't affect the index.  It would only help if I had many duplicate usernames.

Answer (score 2):

Really we can only second guess what the query optimiser will try and do, however it is commonly recommended that if the selectivity of an index over 20% then a full table scan is preferable over an index access.  This would mean it is very likely that even if you index active an index won't actually be used asuming  you have many more active than non-active users.

MySQL can only use the index in order, so if you create a composite index of `username,active` that is entirely pointless as you're not going to have multiple users with the same username.

You really need to analyse your query requirements and then you can design an indexing plan to suite them. Profile each query and don't try to over optimize everything as this can have a negative result.

Answer (score 1):

An index should be added only if the values you expect it to help you filter in/out are representative, statistically speaking.

What does that mean?

If say, the filter in your WHERE clause, on the column you're indexing, is helping you out retrieving 20% of the rows, you should add an index in it. This percent number depends on your   special case and should be tryed out but that's the idea.

In your case, just by the name, you would have 100% of exclusion. Adding an index on the active column would be then useless because it wouldn't help reducing the final recordset (except if you have possibly n times the same name but only one active?)

The situation would be different if you decided to filter ONLY active users, not caring about the name.